# Does Embarcadero RAD Studio XE license allow use on multiple machines?

Tags: delphi, licensing, upgrade

In the past the Borland "no nonsense" license allowed one developer to do multiple installs.

I'm tempted to upgrade to Embarcadero RAD Studio XE, professional edition, but am worried about licensing restrictions, and whether it will allow me to work in the same way as before.

I downloaded a 30 day trial, and that will only allow one install, so I'm a bit concerned the upgrade would enforce a similar restriction.

I use a small and a large laptop and a PC and would like to install RAD Studio on all 3, as well as in VMs. I've posted a question asking about this on the vendor website, but there's no response yet, and I wonder if people could answer from their own experience please?

I'd also be interested to know if the upgrade will only run if there is an existing installation of an earlier product on the same machine.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, you can legally install Rad Studio on more than one machine, as long as you are the only user.  I'm specifically talking about the named user license.

Check the section titled "Installing the product on multiple machines" [here](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/37457).

Comment: Hmm. I bought a "Named ELC" license so I can install on multiple machines. Is a "Named" (without the "ELC") license also available?

Comment: Yes, you can get named licenses without needing a license server.  I'm not sure about what it takes to migrate existing ELC licenses, though.

Comment: My ELC doesn't bother me. What bothers me is that I wasn't offered this option, even those I specifically requested it from my reseller. My guess is that the reseller didn't know about this either. Embarcadero should offer every single possible license through the on-line shop, or train the resellers better. The first option is probably simpler, and cheaper for everyone!

Comment: Thanks - I hope that's the default for an "Electronic Software Delivery", which is how I have purchased an upgrade. I have 7 days to cancel the purchase, so long as I don't use it, so am anxious to understand the licensing before I install. Just want a license that is workable for me - I have found Delphi brilliant for writing Windows UI, one of those rare products that I just clicked with, and have at times shaken my head in disbelief at how productive it can be for me.

Comment: Their EULA does not comply with EU regulations but they still sell licenses in EU. I am talking about: "CodeGear will not transfer a license when: The transfer occurs as a result of the sale of the license to a third-party..."

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can, and you do not need to have a previous version installed. I use it on several machines myself.

Comment: Thanks - hearing of your first hand experience gives me reassurance.